# Split payment process on magento?

Tags: magento, payment-gateway

1. How can we split payment process on magento?

   Suppose i purchased a product from magento store worth of 1000 USD. Im having 500 USD in my credit card and 500 USD in my paypal account. Is it possible to split the payment to purchase this product?

**Note: Not by recurring payment, i want to use more than one payment method for single order..**

1. Is there any option to add MISC amount by admin for the orders that are in pending status  in magento?

Thanks in advance,
Satheesh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no bundled way for this. to achieve this you need to implement a payment method that allows this and enables storing n amount of payment instances to one order.

It's rather easy to implement this with one payment method available and use the transactions method provided by payment api. To achieve multiple different payment methods you must extend the payment api or if you are satisfied with one payment method instance being available you can also use transactions api for this